# Oracle If statement to check for existing records matching the current year

Tags: oracle, toad

I have a table with a column of unique ID numbers where the first part of it is built using sysdate year. The second part of the ID calls a sequence .NEXTVAL to make the ID's Unique.

```
INSERT INTO PLANE_MESSAGES.ALERT_ENTRY (ALERT_ID_FIELD)
    VALUES (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY')||'-'|| LPAD(CTRL_NUM.NEXTVAL,5,'0')
    RETURNING ENTRY_ID INTO v_entry_id;
```

I want to implement an If statement before the insert to check if a record exists in the table that starts with the current YYYY. If not, I want to drop my sequence and re-create it, therefore making the sequence restart yearly. How would I go about creating that syntax?

Comment: Embedding DDL in application code to drop/create objects is generally consider a very bad practice from both a design and security perspective. Sequence values are intended to by *unique*, not necessarily *sequential*. For instance, in order to allow an application to scale, you generally need to cache sequence values for performance, but this often means that values are skipped when the database is restarted and the cache is reloaded. In fact, in some database architectures like RAC, sequential is actually impossible to guarantee when separate caches are created on each cluster node.

Comment: Also, what would happen if multiple inserts were taking place for the first time that year? Dropping the sequence in one program call would potentially blow up any others that came along before the sequence was recreated. Not sure what the rest of your code would look like, but also consider that DDL (drop/create object) generates an implicit commit, so you can't really embed that in the middle of a DML (insert/update/delete) transaction that is potentially incomplete.